# Magento 2: Calling module script, controller, template (app/code/vendor/module) from design (app/design/frontend/vendor)

Tags: magento2, javascript, ajax, ultimo

First of all, I am kind of new in Magento then sorry if my question looks stupid.

I would like to use a template, controller, block, and the script **from my module (app/code)** into the header of my website **made in design (app/design)**, but for the script, I have an error.

Also, a point which might be important I am using theme infortis (Ultimo).

I made a module in **app/code/Vendor/ZipCode** with module.xml, routes.xml, registration.php, ziptemplate.phtml (my template), index.php(my controller), ajax.js, Ziplist.php(my block) and zipcode_zipcode_index.xml.

Then for have this module in my header I overide the design in **app/design/frontend/Vendor/vendor**/Magento_Theme/layout by coping the default.xml from ultimo of infortis and modify so I have app/design/frontend/Vendor/vendor/Magento_Theme/layout/**default.xml** with added:

```
<referenceContainer name="container_header_top_central_1">
                    <block class="Vendor\ZipCode\Block\Ziplist" name="zipForm" template="Vendor_ZipCode::ziptemplate.phtml"></block>
</referenceContainer>
```

For testing Ajax I took from a Stack tutorial this in my template(app/code/Vendor/ZipCode/view/frontend/templates/**ziptemplate.phtml**) :

```
<input type='button' id='zip_btn' name='zip_btn'>
<style>  
.hideme{display:none;}
</style>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
        {
            "*": {
                "Vendor_ZipCode/web/js/ajax": {
                    "AjaxUrl": "<?php echo $block->getAjaxUrl(); ?>"
                }
            }
        }
</script>
<div id='test' class="hideme">
    <select>
      <% _.each(posts, function(text,value) { %>
         <option value="<%= value %>"><%= text %></option>
      <% }) %> 
     </select>
</div>
```

this in my controller (app/code/Vendor/ZipCode/Controller/Zipcode/**index.php**) :

```
<?php 
namespace Vendor\ZipCode\Controller\Zipcode;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
class Index extends Action
{
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory
    ) {

        $this->resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }


    public function execute()
    {
        $result = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();
        if ($this->getRequest()->isAjax()) 
        {
            $test=Array
            (
                'Firstname' => 'What is your firstname',
                'Email' => 'What is your emailId',
                'Lastname' => 'What is your lastname',
                'Country' => 'Your Country'
            );
            return $result->setData($test);
        }
    }
}
```

and this in my script (app/code/Vendor/ZipCode/view/frontend/web/js/**ajax.js**):

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'mage/template',
    'jquery/list-filter'
    ], function (
        $,
        _,
        template
    ) {
        function main(config, element) {
            var $element = $(element);
            var zipurl = config.AjaxUrl;
            console.log('test');
            $(document).on('click','#zip_btn',function() {
                    var param = 'ajax=1';
                        $.ajax({
                            showLoader: true,
                            url: zipurl,
                            data: param,
                            type: "POST",
                            dataType: 'json'
                        }).done(function (data) {
                            $('#test').removeClass('hideme');
                            var html = template('#test', {posts:data}); 
                            $('#test').html(html);
                        });
                });
        };
    console.log('test');
    return main;
});
```

and then I have the following error in the webconsole :

> Loading failed for the  with source
>   “http://dev.mywebsitename.com/pub/static/version1566807153/frontend/Vendor/vendor/en_US/Vendor_ZipCode/web/js/ajax.js”.
>   dev.mywebsitename.com:1 Error: Script error for:
>   Vendor_ZipCode/web/js/ajax
>   http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror

If I understand correctly this error Magento search the script in the design but it is on the module, how can I deal with it (with by preference keeping the script on the module)?
Does someone had the same issue and deal with it?
Thank you in advance.

PS: In case of minus please tell me why so that I can improve my post.

**EDIT (full code):**
for other part of my module code :
-app/code/Vendor/ZipCode/etc/**module.xml** :

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
        <module name="Vendor_ZipCode" setup_version="2.0.0">
            <sequence>
                <module name="Magento_Theme"/>
            </sequence>
        </module>
    </config>
```

app/code/Vendor/Zipcode/etc/frontend/**routes.xml**:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="zipcode" frontName="zipcode">
            <module name="Vendor_ZipCode" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

for app/code/Vendor/ZipCode/**registration.php** :

```php
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Vendor_ZipCode',
    __DIR__
);
```

For app/code/Vendor/ZipCode/Block/**Ziplist.php**:

```php
<?php
namespace Vendor\ZipCode\Block;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class Ziplist extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    public function __construct(Template\Context $context,array $data = array())
    {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->setData('zip','');
    }

    public function setZipcode($zipcode)
    {
        //$_zipcode = $this->getData('zip');
        $this->setData('zip',$zipcode);
    }
}
```

for app/code/Vendor/ZipCode/view/frontend/layout/**zipcode_zipcode_index.xml**:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
            <block class="Infortis\Base\Block\Html\Header" name="base-header-container" before="-" template="html/header.phtml">
                <referenceContainer name="container_header_top_central_1">
                    <block class="Vendor\ZipCode\Block\Ziplist" name="zipForm" template="Vendor_ZipCode::ziptemplate.phtml"></block>
                    </referenceBlock>
                </referenceContainer>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer> <!-- end: page.wrapper -->
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add require js config in your module for frontend

```
Vendor/ZipCode/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js
```

with below content

```
    var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            customNavigation: 'Vendor_ZipCode/js/ajax',
        }
    }
};
```

AND put your JS file in `Vendor/ZipCode/view/frontend/web/js` with below code.

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'mage/template',
    'jquery/list-filter'
], function (
    $,
    _,
    template
) {
    'use strict';
    $.widget('mage.ajaxCall', {
        init: function (options) {
            var $element = $(options.element);
            var zipurl = options.AjaxUrl;
            console.log('test');
            $(document).on('click', '#zip_btn', function () {
                var param = 'ajax=1';
                $.ajax({
                    showLoader: true,
                    url: zipurl,
                    data: param,
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: 'json'
                }).done(function (data) {
                    $('#test').removeClass('hideme');
                    var html = template('#test', {posts: data});
                    $('#test').html(html);
                });
            });
        }
    });
    return $.mage.ajaxCall;
});
```

You need update in your phtml file as below

```
<input type='button' id='zip_btn' name='zip_btn'>
<style>  
.hideme{display:none;}
</style>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
        {
            "*": {
                "Vendor_ZipCode/js/ajax": {
                    "AjaxUrl": "<?php echo $block->getAjaxUrl(); ?>"
                }
            }
        }
</script>
<div id='test' class="hideme">
    <select>
      <% _.each(posts, function(text,value) { %>
         <option value="<%= value %>"><%= text %></option>
      <% }) %> 
     </select>
</div>
```

Comment: I add app/code/Vendor/ZipCode/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js and modify Vendor/ZipCode/view/frontend/web/js/ajax.js, unfortunatly still the same error : 
>Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://dev.mywebsite.com/pub/static/version1566816595/frontend/Vendor/vendor/en_US/Vendor_ZipCode/web/js/ajax.js”.
>Error: Script error for: Vendor_ZipCode/web/js/ajax
>http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror

Comment: Please run flush cache and static content deploy command after that

Comment: Thank you, unfortunatly I did :  
sudo php bin/magento cache:flush  
sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f  
sudo php bin/magento setup:update  
sudo php bin/magento setup:di:compile  
and I still have the same error message in webconsole :(

Comment: @SylvainMichel Please share your full code so I can test it in my system.

Comment: no problem full code for which file do you need ? like from the whole module ?

Comment: @SylvainMichel yes

Comment: ok, I add code from other file in EDIT (full code)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97876/discussion-between-kunj-and-sylvain-michel).

Comment: @SylvainMichel I have updated answer please check it. You just need to change from "Vendor_ZipCode/web/js/ajax" TO "Vendor_ZipCode/js/ajax"

Comment: thank you,I change in my source code like in your updated answer for ziptemplate.phtml unfortunately I still have the same error :/

Comment: sorry is not the same error, Magentot error generator made another one :    
>Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://dev.mywebsite.com/pub/static/version1566826075/frontend/Vendor/vendor/en_US/jquery/list-filter.js”.  
>Error: Script error for: jquery/list-filter

Comment: @SylvainMichel because you do not have `jquery/list-filter` file please remove if not required.

Comment: thank you a lot :) I removed and I have no more error :) but the ajax.js in loaded correctly but nothing happen neither "test" in console for the console.log("test") and nothing when I click the button

Answer (score 0):

You tell that your script is in:

`app/code/Vendor/ZipCode/view/web/js/ajax.js`

...but is has to be in

`app/code/Vendor/ZipCode/view/**frontend**/web/js/ajax.js`

Comment: Sorry my bad it is in app/code/Vendor/ZipCode/view/frontend/web/js/ajax.js, I make I mistake writting the path in stack

Comment: Also, the script error that you received doesn't mean that the script is not found. Instead, the link says this: `This usually means there is a JavaScript syntax error or other execution problem running the script. To fix it, examine the script that generated the error in a script debugger`

Comment: unfortunatly online script debugger open the script from magento core not from mine :(

Comment: Either debug it in your IDE (Eclipse, PHPStorm...) or enter the code directly, for example here https://jshint.com/

Comment: thank you, I am using VS code so I used jshint.com, but it didn't return any error.